# How to rebind to already running bind music player service

Tags: android, service, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

So I just make an music player app and a service that responsible for the mediaplayer class

When I open the fragment in main activity and play music from it, The service is called, make a notification and run in the background... The code that I use to call the service is

```
val auroraServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName,
                                    service: IBinder) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        val binder = service as AuroraService.LocalBinder
        mAuroraService = binder.service
        mBound = true
    }
    override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
        mBound = false
    }
}

fun play(id: Int){ // Called when play and changing music
    Log.v("aurora_l bound", mBound.toString())
    if(!mBound){
        val intent = Intent(activity, AuroraService::class.java)
        intent.action = AuroraService.ServiceAction.PLAY.value
        intent.putExtra("music_id", id)

        activity.startService(intent)
        activity.bindService(intent, auroraServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        mBound = true
    } else {
        mAuroraService.changeMusic(Const.musicUtils.musicById(id))
    }

    update(AuroraService.PlaybackStatus.PLAYING, Const.musicUtils.musicById(id))

    mListener!!.onMusicStateChanged(AuroraService.PlaybackStatus.PLAYING)
}
```

The problem is, when I close the activity(The service still running and playing music) and reopen it again, then play a music, instead of using the old service, it created a new service and play the new song... So, there are two service playing two different music in the same time

But I want there only one service, that will reused

---

Some additional data

My Service Binder

```
class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        internal// Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        val service: AuroraService
            get() = this@AuroraService
    }
```

onBind method from my service

```
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        initMediaSession() // Init media sessions class for notification
        iInitMediaPlayer() // Init mediaplayer callback
        if (intent != null) {
            iReceiveAction(intent)
        }
        return mBinder
    }

fun iReceiveAction(intent: Intent){
        val mAction = ServiceAction.values().lastOrNull { intent.action == it.value }
                ?: ServiceAction.NONE

        when (mAction){
            ServiceAction.PLAY -> {
                val musicId = intent.getIntExtra("music_id", -1)
                music = Const.musicUtils.musicById(musicId)
                musicInPlaylist = musicId
                playlist = ArrayList()

                plauMusic()
            }
            else -> {
                Log.v("aurora_", "?!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"So, there are two service playing two different music in the same time"` no, a service is a singleton: you cannot have two instances (or more) of the same service

Comment: @pskink so why there are two music playing in the same time? Is it just the mediaplayer that recreated?

Comment: when your service dies you dont kill your media player - and that beast survives playing your audio

Comment: Before starting and binding to any service, especially a music player service, always check if there is already a running instance of the service. If there's already one running, then do not call `startService` again, just `bindService`.

Also, do not pass the BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag to the `bindService` if, most of the time, there are no bound connections to the service because when you use that flag, the service will stop itself when there are no more bound service connections. I'm not really sure though if that's still the case when `startService` is called before `bindService`.

Comment: Also, make sure that you perform necessary resource clean up or destruction on the `Service.onDestroy()` method. I totally agree with @pskink. Audio related object instances usually require explicit clean up, e.g. `Spotify.destroyPlayer()`.